# How to get the row and column index conditional on Boolean, and apply said index to another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, boolean

I have 2 dataframes, `res_params` and `res_tStats`. The columns and index is identical in both dataframes. It's only the *values* within each row and column (equivalent to "cells" in Excel if you will) that are different.

I need to get the index of the rows and columns from the `res_tStats` dataframe where `abs(res_tStats) > 1.96` and then apply formatting to the *same index and rows* in the `res_params` data frame.

### What I've done

```
# res_tStats is a NxM dataframe with shape (6, 4)
# res_params is a NXM dataframe with shape (6, 4)

idx_required = np.where(abs(res_tStats) > 1.96)

print(idx_required)
# output: array([0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5]), array([0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

So far so good. It gave me the right index locations for where `abs(res_tStats) > 1.96`.
The following values are in fact significant:

row 0, col 0
row 0, col 2
row 0, col 3
row 5, col 0
row 5, col 1
row 5, col 2
row 5, col 3

Now, when I apply these index locations to `res_params`, I'm expecting to get the values at precisely the same index locations. However, I don't quite get that.

Running: `res_params.iloc[idx_required]` returns a df of shape (7, 7).

I double checked by applying `idx_required` to `res_tStats`, expecting to get only the values > 1.96, however that didn't happen.
`res_tStats.iloc[idx_required]`  also returns a df of shape (7, 7) with some values within it being lower than 1.96

Comment: Please provide samples of your input dataframes, sample of your output, and sample of your expected output, to make a [mcve] we can test against. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `idx_required` is a tuple with indeces and columns, and  `.iloc` selects those in a cross-product way if you pass a tuple.

A simple fix is:

```py
res_params[np.abs(res_tStats)>1.96]
```

This will return a dataframe with values of `res_params` where `np.abs(res_tStats)>1.96` and `NaN` where the condition does not hold true.

Another way, is to get the list of elements as:

```py
res_params.to_numpy()[idx_required]
```

This way you will get the list of elements, without the respective index or column.

Comment: FBruzzesi, you're a star. This works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you want a single *1D array* or a Series with the 5 expected elements along with their indices.

A possible way would be the use the indices of the columns and stack the dataframe:

```
res_param.set_axis(range(len(res_param.columns)), axis=1, inplace=False).stack()[zip(*idx_required)]
```

It should give you a Series with the indices as a MultiIndex and the relevant values.

Comment: Cheers Serge, however I need the values within the dataframe itself since I'll be applying formatting to the values which meet the condition on the other df. The solution below works well. Many thanks for your response though!